# Facing issue while sending the JSON to Controller Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to send the Json Data to my Controller Action.

**JQuery**

```
function SaveConnection() {
    debugger;
    var CardConnection = {
        ConnectionDetails: []
    };

    var allConn = jsPlumb.getAllConnections();
    var length = allConn["green dot"].length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        CardConnection.ConnectionDetails.push({
            "CardIDFrom": allConn["green dot"][i].sourceId,
            "CardIDTo": allConn["green dot"][i].targetId
        });
    }

    var CardDetails = $('#CardDetails');
    var url = CardDetails.attr('save-data');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(CardConnection),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    return false;
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult SaveConnections(List<CardConnection> ConnectionList)
{
    return Json(ConnectionList);
}
```

Issue is - It is always showing null in the Argument of Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable should be like this

```
var CardConnection = {
        ConnectionList: []
    };
```

It should not be like this

```
var CardConnection = {
        ConnectionDetails: []
    };
```

Why ?

In action argument the variable name is `ConnectionList`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. The solution was to tell iis the mime type of json, because it cannot handle it by default.

Add 
`<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>`

to web.config as child of system.webServer.

Comment: This applies only when JSON data is served directly by IIS (i.e. a local .json file.) The question asked shows a controller action with `return Json(...)`. This suggests this is not the case, so this won't work.